# How do I get my controller to return just 2 attributes of an object in a json response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3

So I would like to just get back the `:id, :name` attributes of my `@neighborhood` object in my `json` response.

This is my action in my controller:

```
  def autocomplete_neighborhood_name
    @neighborhood = Neighborhood.select("id, name").where("name LIKE ?", "#{params[:name]}%").order(:name).limit(10)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { @neighborhood :only => [:id, :name]}
    end    
  end
```

I am getting a syntax error on the `format.json...` line.

How do I do accomplish what I want?

Thanks.

**Edit 1**

My real goal is to try and refactor this code, to use `format.json` and use the newer methods of Rails 3.2.x:

```
def autocomplete_neighborhood_name
  respond_with(
    Neighborhood.
      select("id, name").
      where("name LIKE ?", "#{params[:name]}%").
      order(:name).
      limit(10).
      as_json(:only => [:id, :name]))      
end
```

If you have any other suggestions for how I might do this better, I would appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
format.json { render json: @neighborhood , :only => [:id, :name] }
```

Comment: I just updated the question...see the old code I am refactoring - any other suggestions for how I might make my version any better?

Comment: Actually...nevermind...your solution works wonderfully. Thanks!